# Jquery Isotope Checkbox filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery isotope. Everything is ok but I have problem with filtering. I want to use multiple categories I have 5 checkboxes and I can't use them at the same time. What can I do?

```
$("#classic").click(function() {
    if($("#classic").is(":checked")) {
    $('#box').isotope({ filter: '.classic' });
    } else {
    $('#box').isotope({ filter: '' });
    }
});
```

Example

my items = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

categories = x ( a,b,e) y (c,h) z(d,f,g)

now if I choose the x and z checkbox it only show the a,b,e,d,f,g

but I can't do that. How can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a js error in the code(missing single quote) and also at one place classic is used as an id and at another place as a class. Just wanted to find if thats not the issue. Try this.

```
function checkIsoTope(){
    var ids = [];
    $("#classic, #den, #wer").filter(":checked").each(function(){
      ids.push("." + this.id);
    });    
    $('#box').isotope({ filter: ids.join(',')});
}
$("#classic, #den, #wer, #allCheckboxId").click(checkIsoTope);
```

Comment: No it's working, This is just sample for one checkbox if I use to other checkbox it's not working

Comment: What are the ids for those checkboxes?

Comment: #classic , #den, #wer

Example

my items = a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h

categories = x ( a,b,e) y (c,h) z(d,f,g)

now if I choose the x and z checkbox it only show the a,b,e,d,f,g

but I can't do that. How can I do ?

Comment: Thank you but this is not working I'm using class for filter and this is true syntax for filter 

{ filter: '.example1','.example3','.example3' }

id name and class name same in my code how can I fix the code ?

Comment: What are the class names for these 3 checkboxes?

Comment: and last question :) i have a all checkbox which choose all checkboxes how can i use in same fuction if i click the all checkbox it'll change all and when i uncheck it it'll remove all

Comment: Check my edited answer and in that replace the all checkbox id correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution for checkbox filtering:
http://jsfiddle.net/3nY9V/6/

Comment: This so cool!!!, but I'm not sure how to apply it when dealing with two filter dimensions.  For example if you have one set for color and another for shape and I click circle and square, I would only want to see items that meet both requirements where this would bring back all circles (regardless of color) and all items that are red (regardless of shape).  I would be happy to submit a question if you can help.

Comment: Thank you! Just an add that i found on another topic:

To make an "Show all" checkbox, just add this line 

$container.isotope({ filter: ( filters == null || filters.length == 0 ) ? 'default' : filters });